# Won't write to plist array Xcode. This was the code used and it doesn't work, does anyone know why?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, storage, plist

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HighScore.plist"];
NSMutableArray* plistDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                             initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];   
[plistDict addObject:[highScoreLabel  text]];
NSArray *regArray =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:plistDict];
[regArray writeToFile:@"HighScore.plist" atomically: YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the file exist and contains valid data?

See Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithContentsOfFile%3a) about `NSMutableArray initWithContentsOfFile:`:

> Return Value
>
> An array initialized to contain the contents of the file specified by aPath or nil if the file can’t be opened or the contents of the file can’t be parsed into an array. The returned object might be different than the original receiver.
>
> Discussion
>
> The array representation in the file identified by aPath must contain only property list objects (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects). The objects contained by this array are immutable, even if the array is mutable.

If `initWithContentsOfFile:` returns `nil`, it's clear that the rest of the code won't work either.

Comment: So should the code work above? Because I want the text label to save to a plist.

Answer (score 0):

p list write to file means to write the p list or to save the data ,,,for retrieving view write the content of file .